# display node's field in <table>

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

Is it possible to display a node's field in a table? Is there any module providing it?

For example I have a node "English idioms" which has a field named: "Idiom" and "Explanation". I would like to put them both in a (table->tr->td - each).

At the moment I have these fields in div's with classes but I would like to avoid it if it's possible.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [field_group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) nad [field_group_table](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_table)

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.